# Java Generics - Why is this method call considered an unchecked conversion

Tags: java, generics, scjp, ocpjp

The following code examples compiles but with a compiler warning

```
class Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal{}
class Cat extends Animal{}

class SubArrayList<T> extends ArrayList{}

class ZiggyTest2{

    public static void main(String[] args){                 
        ArrayList<Animal> nums = new SubArrayList<Animal>();

    }

    public static void testMethod(ArrayList<Animal> anim){
        System.out.println("In TestMethod");
    }
}
```

When i compile the above i get the following warning

```
Note: ZiggyTest2.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Or if i compile it with -Xlint:unchecked i get the following warning

```
ZiggyTest2.java:12: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
found   : SubArrayList<Animal>
required: java.util.ArrayList<Animal>
                ArrayList<Animal> nums = new SubArrayList<Animal>();
                                         ^
1 warning
```

If i change the initialisation of nums to

```
List<Animal> nums = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

then i dont get any warnings.

Why are they behaving differently. ArrayList is a subtype of List and SubArrayList is a subtype of ArrayList so i was expecting the instantiation to be the same.

Thanks.

### Edit

Also if i call the method and pass it an reference initialised generically it also produces a warning.

```
class Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal{}
class Cat extends Animal{}

class SubArrayList<T> extends ArrayList{}

class ZiggyTest2{

    public static void main(String[] args){                 
        SubArrayList<Animal> nums = new SubArrayList<Animal>();
        testMethod(nums);

    }

    public static void testMethod(ArrayList<Animal> anim){
        System.out.println("In TestMethod");
    }
}
```

I thought compiler warnings will only appear if you mix generic code with non-generic code.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `SubArrayList<T>` class only extends `ArrayList` (essentially `ArrayList<?>`), and not `ArrayList<T>`, making a cast from `SubArrayList<T>` to `ArrayList<T>` unchecked.

If you change it to `class SubArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {}`, you will not have the problem anymore :)

Answer (score 3):

Add a `<T>` to your ArrayList as in

```
class SubArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T>{}
```

Answer (score 2):

`List` is an interface, not a class. ArrayList isn't a subclass of List, simply a class that implements the List interface. SubArrayList is, however, a subclass of ArrayList.